# Reactjs filter not returning correct users, when i delete the characters in the search filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching the users from dummyapi and i am listing them. There is a search input, i want to filter the users on the page by name. When i type the characters, it filters correctly. When i start to delete the character, users are not listed correctly. It remains filtered. How can i fix this ? This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import User from "./User";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const BASE_URL = "https://dummyapi.io/data/api";
  const APP_ID = "your app id";
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const keyword = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredUsers =
      users &&
      users.filter((user) => user.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(keyword));
    setUsers(filteredUsers);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=1`, {
          headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
        });
        setUsers(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="filter">
          <h3 className="filter__title">USER LIST</h3>
          <div>
            <input
              id="filter"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by name"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="user__grid">
          {users &&
            users.map((user, index) => {
              const { id } = user;
              return <User key={index} id={id} />;
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are manipulating the original array of users. So after each filter the original array has less values than previous hence after deleting it will search from the reduced number of elements.
To avoid this, keep original way as it is, apply filter on that and store the result in a separate array.
Something like this:

```
  const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState(null);  //will store original records
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null); // will store filtered results
```

then in `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=1`, {
          headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
        });
        setUsers(response.data.data);
        setAllUsers(response.data.data); //add this line
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

and finally in `handleChange` event:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const keyword = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // use allUsers array (with original unchanged data)
    const filteredUsers =
      allUsers &&
      allUsers.filter((user) => user.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(keyword));
    setUsers(filteredUsers);
  };
```

Obviously, you can use some better approach, but this is just to give the idea of original issue.